# install complete LAMP stack for 14.04 to install wordpress

Tags: 14.04, apache2, lamp, wordpress

I want to install complete LAMP stack on my Ubuntu 14.04 in order to install Wordpress.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

I am trying to install APACHE with the above and here's the error I am getting

```
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php5 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anyone recommend the best method to get the up and running.

Thanks

Comment: You can also try `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`...

Answer (score 1):

There are some packages missing. Install everything needed by running :

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql-server libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql
```

If you need `phpmyadmin` afterwards, install it :

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Comment: I already tried this but it returns another error.

`Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

This is what I get after I run this command

Comment: @Suraj , try `apt-get update` first, then `apt-get -f install`. Option -f should fix your problems , then install your LAMP stack

Comment: `W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/langdalepl/gvfs-mtp/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/langdalepl/gvfs-mtp/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
`

Get this error on `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: For this error, please refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/65911/338915).

Comment: tried these answers but getting those erros after that too

Comment: Okay, So I am have the `apt-get-update`, but when I run `sudo apt-get install apache2` I am  getting the same erros as the question

Comment: Is your distro 32bit or 64bit ? Run `uname -a` and paste.

Comment: `x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 0):

Run:
`sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/langdalepl-gvfs-mtp-trusty.list`
`sudo apt-get update`

The run again `sudo apt-get install apache2`

Your have not working repository called "gvfs"

Comment: `dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
`   The same error

Comment: Run : `sudo dpkg -l |grep apache` and `sudo dpkg -l |grep php` and paste the results here.

Comment: `grep: and: No such file or directory
grep: sudo: No such file or directory
grep: dpkg: No such file or directory
`

Comment: You got something wrong with copy/paste . The results shoudl be like mine: `root@ac:~# dpkg -l |grep apache
ii  apache2                             2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+4       amd64        Apache HTTP Server
....
root@ac:~# dpkg -l |grep php
...
ii  php5                                5.6.16+dfsg-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1  all         `

Comment: [here's](http://pastebin.com/mRgzB9aV) the first command result. And [second](http://pastebin.com/4R2MnvPz) command result.

Comment: Ok, so remove zlangdalepl-gvfs-mtp` repo. Then be sure that there is no more gvfs files in your apt configuration by `grep gvfs /etc/apt/* -r` , then remove your `libapache2-mod-php5` by `apt-get remove --purge libapache2-mod-php5` and install it again. I hope this helps.